# Strange mouse bug on linux

Tags: linux, mouse, archlinux

On the laptop is sometimes spontaneously mouse runs across the screen . Movements are not like lucid . This continues even when you connect the wireless mouse . Now I use arch.

Comment: Please use http://unix.stackexchange.com/ community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my experience mouse related problems are in most cases due to mechanical or physical problems like the material of the table or stuff stuck on the sensor.

Try if this still happens when the mouse is disconnected, if it is a laptop it might be because you are touching the touch-pad without knowing. 
As Erick pointed, check if it happens only on Linux and if its really a problem of the OS or the mouse itself.

You may also want to check [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/345981/unintentional-mouse-movements-am-i-paranoid?newreg=7573919e86ab4900b5f3554eefe5653f) on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen only on Linux? 
I had a problem like this once, when my laptop was connected to an not-well-grounded power outlet in University (all plugs in a particular room were like that). The electrostatic was interfering with the touchpad.

Comment: On windows did not notice this problem.